How can I pull AppLifecycleState.resume in Flutter when the application's state is AppLifecycleState.paused
My application is an information screen application that works on a tablet 24 hours a day. That's why it should never turn off from the screen. But sometimes it falls off the screen and continues to run in the background. Can I trigger it to run on the screen again when it falls into the background with codes?
Thanks in advance for your answers
I can print lifecycle states, but I cannot change their states.

if you have continuous work to do, its better to use a foreground service, alarmmanager preferably workmanager depending on the type of work

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
